# TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Invalid name WITH Yelp API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

Having trouble fetching the Yelp API in my react native app. Here is my code:

```
      const getRestaurantsFromYelp = async (req, res) => {
    const yelpUrl = `https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=restaurants&location=NYC`;
    const apiOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
         accept: 'application/json',
        'x- requested - wth': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
         Authorization: `Bearer ${YELP_API_KEY}`,
      },
    };
    return await fetch(yelpUrl, apiOptions)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => setRestaurantData(json.businesses));
 };

  useEffect(() => {
    getRestaurantsFromYelp();
  }, []);
```

Comment: This solution got me 1 step further but now I have errors saying SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (at Home.js:48:1)

Answer (score 1):

Your options object is not correct. Please remove
`x- requested - wth` as the wrong key or fix it.
Also, use the same type of key in your code the options have different type of keys with quotes and without.

So, I think this code should work.

```
    const yelpUrl = `https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=restaurants&location=NYC`;
    const apiOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
         'accept': 'application/json',
         'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
         'Authorization': `Bearer ${YELP_API_KEY}`,
      },
    };

    const response = await fetch(yelpUrl, apiOptions)
    const { businesses } = response.json(); 
    setRestaurantData(businesses);
```

Comment: Probably best not to assign parsed JSON to a variable called `json`. You can also destructure the `businesses` prop from the data, and then set state with it. `const { businesses } = await res.json(); setRestaurantData(businesses);` so no need to return anything from the function.

Comment: @Andy good suggestion, updated!

Comment: And that should be `await response.json()` :)

Comment: This solution got me 1 step further but now I have errors saying SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (at Home.js:48:1)